# EcomDev_PHPUnit set up in Magento EE 1.13

Tags: configuration, ecomdev-phpunit, ee-1.12, unit-tests

I am trying to set up EComDev_PHPUnit in EE 1.13 as per the instructions in

https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit

Well first hurdle was to get modman working but I gave up and copied over the modules manually. Now the second issue is in the step 2: when I execute

```
php ecomdev-phpunit.php -a magento-config --db-name $DB_NAME --base-url http://your.magento.url/
```

I get an exception that says

```
 PHP Fatal error : Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Factory' not found in '../../../shell/abstract.php' on line 88
```

I went and added the factory path with require_once in abstract.pho but then it throws up an error saying another class is missing...

Has anyone encountered this? I am using Ubuntu 12.10 in a VirtualBox. Any help on this will be appreciated.

***Solution or temporary solution:***

I had to add

```
require_once '../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Factory.php';
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
```

as the first lines of `../shell/ecomdev-phpunit.php`

Which made it work fine. I am not sure if it is right or wrong :) Expert suggestions welcome
(stackexchange does not let me add a solution within 8 hrs of asking question and I have a low reputation, hence adding the answer here)

Answer (score 5):

Based on updates above, it looks like the original asker solved their problem by

> Solution or temporary solution:
>
> I had to add
>
> require_once '../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Factory.php';
>
> require_once '../app/Mage.php';
>
> as the first lines of ../shell/ecomdev-phpunit.php
>
> Which made it work fine. I am not sure if it is right or wrong :) Expert suggestions welcome (stackexchange does not let me add a solution within 8 hrs of asking question and I have a low reputation, hence adding the answer here)

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, the latest dev branch of EcomDev_PHPUnit codebase now resolves this issue, making it compatible for EE1.13 and CE1.8:

https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/commit/669230422da701ba53b1cc5f98f17ccb273e3b9e

Comment: Can you point to the actual commit instead of the dev tree? That way we can see what fixes it, as I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just throwing a note here (maybe it'll be helpful). There's a protected variable called `$_includeMage` which is set to `false` for some reason.

Setting it to `true` resolves the issue and doesn't require adding those files Alan mentioned explicitly. Since `Mage` is imported in `Mage_Shell_Abstract` class, and `Mage_Core_Model_Factory` is imported by autoloader (which is registered by `Mage`).